# Customize nested form template (via collection field) in Symfony 2

Tags: forms, symfony

I am looking for a way to customize the form which is called in my collection field.

My default theme set input under each other (which is nice). For this specific nested form I want input to be set side by side.

I did not find the anwswer in the documentation (I found how to customize the collection field block but not this specific form inside it).

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to render each form fields separatly, each field will be render, and you will be able to add classes / id and other options

```
<div class="small-12 medium-6 columns contactFormBlock">
    {{ form_start(form, { 'attr': { 'id': 'contactForm' }, 'method': 'POST' }) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.author, { 'attr': { 'class': 'large-6 columns contactAuthor', 'placeholder': 'contact.form.author' | trans } }) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.email, { 'attr': { 'class': 'large-6 columns contactEmail', 'placeholder': 'contact.form.email' | trans } }) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.subject, { 'attr': { 'class': 'contactSubject', 'placeholder': 'contact.form.subject' | trans } }) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.message, { 'attr': { 'class': 'contactMessage', 'placeholder': 'contact.form.message' | trans } }) }}
        <input class="large-3 columns button float-right sendButton" type="submit" value="{{ 'chat.chatPart.form.button' | trans }}">
    {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```

Then use `CSS` to modify the render style of your form.

Hope this will help you.